# Current in the Dirac equation

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, interactions

In the Dirac Hamiltonian the current that couples with the vector potential is:
\begin{equation}
j^{\mu} = \bar{\psi}(x)\gamma^{\mu}\psi(x)
\end{equation}
However, in the non relativistic context, the current is defined as:
\begin{equation}
j_{p} = \sum_{i}Z_{i}\dot{q}_{i,p}\delta(r-r_{i})
\end{equation}
where $p$ is the spacial component, $i$ are a group of charged particles with charge $Z_{i}$.

I am wondering how comes the current in the dirac equation does not involve derivative of the field and how the equivalence between the two formulations is obtained. Also, I am wondering if the current used in the Dirac Hamiltonian takes into account of the contributions due to the spin.

Comment: You may find all you want in any QED lecture.

Comment: Have you compared with the definition of current from Schrödinger equation?

Comment: What do you mean by the definition of current from the Schr\"{o}dinger equation? Isn't it the same that I have in the second equation of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a Lagrangian, we can find the current by identifying terms of the form $J^\mu A_\mu$. A free Dirac field has the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} = i\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi -m \bar\psi\psi$. To add an electromagnetic interaction, we change $\partial_\mu \rightarrow D_\mu=  \partial_\mu -ie A_\mu$. This gives us the interaction term $e\bar\psi\gamma^\mu A_\mu\psi$ and so a current $e\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi$